# can't post data via ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to post to the controller some data that I retrieve from the form. Here is my form:

```
<div id="time_registration" class="toogle_form" diplay="none">
<form id="hourForm" name="hourForm"  >
//first part of the form -----
```

//second part:

```
    <div id="hoursDetails" class="toogle_form" style="display:none"> 
        <table border=0>
                        <?php
                           for ($i=0 ; $i<3; $i++){
                   echo '<tr>
                      <td><div id="date'.$i.'" name="date'.$i.'" ></div></td>   
                      <input type=hidden id="date'.$i.'" name="date'.$i.'" value=""/>

                      <td>
                      <input type=text name="action'.$i.'"  placeholder="Votre action" value=""/>
                      <input type="text" name="temps'.$i.'"  placeholder="nombre heures" value=""/>
                      </td>
                  </tr> ';}
                echo '  <input type=hidden id="dateTest" name="dateTest" value=""/>  '; // just to test  
                  ?>
                  </table>
    </div> 
  </form>
</div>
```

Firebug shows that date0, date1 and date2 are empty but dateTest is not.

Here is how I set my variables ( js function)

```
         for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

              $('#date'+i).html('myVariable');
              $('#date'+i).val('myVariable');
                 }
              $('#dateTest').val('dateTest');
```

And here is how I post the data to the controller :

```
function insert_hour() {
         var form_values= $('#hourForm').serialize();
         alert($('#date0').val());// prints the correct value also for date1 and date2

         $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
                url : '<?php echo site_url()."/path/to/controller/"; ?>',
            data : form_values,

            success:function(data)
                {   alert(' ajax_call ok ');
                }

            });     


}
```

Comment: What does Firebug show you is being passed to the server?  What does the server see?  What does the server return?

Comment: firebug shows that date0 date1 date2 are posted but are empty. So the server receives empty variables. Only dateTest is not empty and it contains 'dateTest'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing here wrong

```
<div id="date'.$i.'" name="date'.$i.'" >

      and

<input type=hidden id="date'.$i.'" name="date'.$i.'" value=""/>
```

In this case `$('#date'+i).html('myVariable'); Will not work`

You are using same id.Id must be unique.

Comment: thank you. That was the mistake

Comment: @user1499220 yours very welcome